# CentOS: How do I go about setting up GIT on a CentOS server per the following

Tags: git, centos

I would like to setup git for a website taking the following into account:

I have a VPS setup where I plan on doing the following:

1. Setup /home/site/public_html (Main Website)
2. Setup /home/dev-site/public_html (Dev Site)
3. Use an IDE on my Windows PC to make changes.

I would like to see the following happen:

1. I make changes on my local PC
2. Push to my DEV site (dev-site) for testing
3. If everything works there, I would then push to my Main Website(LIVE)

What is the best approach to have something like this work.

I just now started to use GIT and it is getting a little confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a central repo for your code (github, gitlab ect..)

Create two branches in git (master & dev)

Always checkout the dev branch for your work. (Never master)

```
windowsComupter$ git checkout dev
```

When you are happy with the results, upload your commit

```
windowsComputer$ git commit
windowsComputer$ git push
```

On your development site, pull down the latest dev repo

```
dev-site$ git pull origin dev
```

When you have tested everything, merge dev into master

```
windowsComputer$ git checkout master
windowsComputer$ git merge dev
```

Go to your production site, and checkout the latest master

```
productionServer$ git pull origin master
```

Let me know if that doesn't answer your question and I'll expound further.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, I am not using any service like github. I am developing in my PC and I want to PUSH to my DEV server for testing (which is the save server, but diff user accnt). When I am happy with everything, I want to access my DEV server and PUSH to my LIVE server (Remote). How do I go about doing that? What are the best approach? Specifically, I want to have DEV setup, CLONE from the DEV into my PC. When ready, commit and push to DEV and push from DEV to LIVE, when I want to make my changes public. I am getting confused with all this and I dont know where to start.

Comment: I was able to figure it out after a few tries. I setup my LIVE site first, then cloned from it to the DEV site and then cloned the DEV to my PC. It now works great. Thanks for helping me to get there. When I make a change in my PC I use Git Extensions to push it to the DEV and test it there. If I am happy with everything I will go a `git push` from DEV to LIVE.